# colon and spaces daredevil

Tags: java, time

I almost finished my program then suddenly there's a problem. How can I enter a space or colon sometime in my output without having some errors? 
Here is the example how my output would look like.

```
    TIME DIFFERENCE

Enter first time (hh:mm aa): 12 00 pm
Enter second time (hh:mm aa): 12:00 am
Do you wish to continue (Y/N)?: 
n
The difference is 720 minutes and 0 seconds.
```

here is my program

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass9 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = 'y';
    public static void main(String[] args)throws ParseException
    {
        NewClass9 t = new NewClass9();
        t.StudentInfo();

        while(t.choice == 'y') {

            t.Time();
        }
    }

    public void StudentInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Name:");
        System.out.println("Student Id:");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Tutor:");
        System.out.println("Tutorial:");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    public void Time() throws ParseException
    {

 System.out.print("TIME DIFFERENCE" + "\n\n" 
         + "Enter first time (hh:mm aa): ");
 String time1 = input.nextLine();
 System.out.print("Enter second time (hh:mm aa): ");
 String time2 = input.nextLine();


 System.out.print("Do you wish to continue (Y/N)?: ");
        choice = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        choice = Character.toLowerCase(choice);

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        Date d1 = sdf.parse(time1);
        Date d2 = sdf.parse(time2);

    if(d1.after(d2)){
     long diffMs = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
     long diffSec = diffMs / 1000;
     long min = diffSec / 60;
     long sec = diffSec % 60;
     System.out.println("The difference is "+min+" minutes and "+sec+" seconds.");
    }

    if(d1.before(d2)){
     long diffMs = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
     long diffSec = diffMs / 1000;
     long min = diffSec / 60;
     long sec = diffSec % 60;
     System.out.println("The difference is "+min+" minutes and "+sec+" seconds.");
    }

    if(d1.equals(d2)){
     System.out.println("The difference is 0 minutes and 0 seconds.");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: i want to put spaces instead of colon in the 12:56 pm output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceFirst(" ",":")` to replace the first space with `:` after taking the input.

```
System.out.print("TIME DIFFERENCE" + "\n\n" 
              + "Enter first time (hh:mm aa): ");
String time1 = input.nextLine().replaceFirst(" ",":");
System.out.print("Enter second time (hh:mm aa): ");
String time2 = input.nextLine().replaceFirst(" ",":");
```

With this, a sample interaction would be:

> Enter first time (hh:mm aa): 12 56 pm
>   Enter second time (hh:mm aa): 14 00 pm
>   Do you wish to continue (Y/N)?: n
>   The difference is 784 minutes and 0 seconds.

---

As you have said that you may need both the formats at the same time, then you may modify this part of your code:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
Date d1 = sdf.parse(time1);
Date d2 = sdf.parse(time2);
```

As follows:

```
DateFormat sp_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm aa");
DateFormat co_sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
Date d1, d2;
try{
    d1 = sp_sdf.parse(time1);
}catch(java.text.ParseException e){
    d1 = co_sdf.parse(time1);   
}

try{
    d2 = sp_sdf.parse(time2);
}catch(java.text.ParseException e){
    d2 = co_sdf.parse(time2);   
}
```